# What constructs a image byte array?

Tags: image, file, bitmap, byte, jpeg

I just know that each type of image has a unique header. Just like`.JPG` image file byte aray always starts with `FFD8 FF`, `.BMP` file always start with `424d`(which means ascii byte `BM`).

But I really wonder the construction of rest part of a image byte array, does anybody know about that?

Answer (score 0):

Rest of binary file is just a byte sequence. Form header you know such parameters as width, height, bit depth, amount of channels and compression algorithm if data is compressed.

So image data is just sequence of bytes. That sequence is decoded using information from header. For specific header format you need to check image format documentation.